# How to remove non-numeric characters (except full stop "." ) from a string in amazon redshift

Tags: sql, string, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have been trying to figure out how to remove multiple  `non-numeric` characters except full stop `(".")`, or return only the numeric characters with full stop `(".")` from a string. I've tried:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('~ï¿½$$$1$$#1633,123.60&&!!__!', '[^0-9]+', '')
```

This query returns following result : `1163312360`

But I want the result as `11633123.60`

Comment: I haven't tried it but you might just try the following SELECT regexp_replace('~ï¿½$$$1$$#1633,123.60&&!!__!', '[^0-9.]+', '')

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try this:

The below regex_replace expression will replace all character which are not ("^") in the (range of 0-9) & "."

```
SELECT regexp_replace('ABC$$$%%11633123.60','([^0-9.])','') FROM DUAL;
```

It returns the expected output `"11633123.60"`